# Shipping Address Verification Magento2

Tags: magento2, webapi

Can someone help me in guiding available API's or any suitable extension for shipping address verification in magento 2 commerce website.

Answer (score 1):

Can you be more specific please? How do you plan to verify the shipping address? As far as i know magento does not do this out-of-the-box

Comment: Hello Jinnn, my requirement is to validate customer address on checkout page so shipping should process to valid address. So I am looking for a guidance that can direct me how can I achieve this functionality. 

Is there any API that I can use then please let me know. I will use it to create a functionality for address verification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes SmartyStreets has [address verification APIs](https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-street-api) that work with Magento2. Here a module I found on GitHub: https://github.com/thinkpyxl/magento2-Pyxl_SmartyStreets

It looks like it still uses SmartyStreets basic autocomplete tool but I would suggest using the [Autocomplete Pro API](https://smartystreets.com/products/apis/us-autocomplete-pro-api). The basic version is no longer supported.

It shouldn't be too difficult to make the change. The pro version is faster, prioritizes results based on user location, included apartment numbers in the predictions and won't give fake addresses.